# Sql alchemy sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError not creating tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with flask and trying to learn sqlalchemy, I have a database where I added a third table to make a new feature, but the entire project stopped working, it says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'url_reference.folder_rel' could not find table 'reffolders' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

this is the `dbs.py`

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
  
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    user_password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(400))
    user_refs = db.relationship("RefFolders")

class RefFolders(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    folder_title = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_rel = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    url_rel = db.relationship("UrlReference")

class UrlReference(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ref_title = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    ref_url = db.Column(db.String(30000))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    folder_rel = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("reffolders.id"))
```

this is where I make the database in the `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
 
DB_NAME = "database.db"
 
def app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<here is the key in my code>'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
    db.init_app(app)
 
    # making the blueprints usable
  
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")
  
    from .dbs import User
    from .dbs import UrlReference
    from .dbs import RefFolders
 
    db_create(app)
 
    # Login manager
  
    login_manager= LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'views.home'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
  
    # Searching and loading user
  
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))
   
    return app
 
def db_create(app):
    if not path.exists("project/" + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
```

I don't know what happened, maybe a problem with having a double foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think flask or its extension guesses the table name you want, like CamelCase --> camel_case.

So in this case the tablename is probably `ref_folders`.  You might want to just use **tablename** to set the table name yourself although I think their default is a good convention.

As a side note I would recommend using `_id` for your ids otherwise things might get pretty confusing between object relations and actual ids, ie. use `user_id` instead of `user_rel` in `RefFolders`.

SEE:

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#declaring-models

> Some parts that are required in SQLAlchemy are optional in
> Flask-SQLAlchemy. For instance the table name is automatically set for
> you unless overridden. It’s derived from the class name converted to
> lowercase and with “CamelCase” converted to “camel_case”. To override
> the table name, set the `__tablename__` class attribute.